# Why do I get "We're sorry, but something went wrong." after restoring via pgbackups:restore with no migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, heroku

This one took me a while to figure out. It's pretty tricky and seems like a bug in Heroku, so I will post my own answer in case it helps someone.

**Scenario**:

- Rails application using postgresql adapter works fine on localhost.
- All migrations are complete.
- Deploying to Heroku via "git push heroku master" successfully updates Heroku instance.
- Heroku PGBackups addon is installed and works fine.
- pg_dump was used to generate a local db dump, and the file uploaded to an accessible internet location.

**Problem**:

After running

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_URL 'http://mywebsite.com/pgbackup.dump'
```

I get the "something went wrong" message. Strange, considering all that happened was a database load, a database whose data works fine on the local machine. No migrations were performed, everything has been committed previously, no code updates... Only data in the database was changed, so why does the app no longer work if just data in the database changed?

Checking the `heroku logs` shows that it can't find tables that are clearly there. Lines like:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

Verifying with `heroku pg:psql` just makes the situation even stranger, because doing `select * from users` brings back the real results. Even performing a `heroku restart` at this stage won't get rid of the problem. I also tried combinations of that with `heroku pg:reset` and `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

**Why does updating data in the database shut down the app?**

Comment: I had weird behavior that was somewhat similar once, and it seemed tied to the automatic id indices on tables that had been renamed.  For me pg:reset immediately followed by loading the dump file did the trick.  Sounds like you probably already tried that, but just in case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Run the `pgbackups:restore` as originally intended (and get error).
2. Run `heroku restart`.
3. Run `heroku pg:psql` (profit).

For some reason, it seems necessary to `restart` and then `pg:psql` before the database works after a `pg:restore`.

Even though `pg:psql` will gladly show that the tables are indeed there (contrary to the log messages), the app won't work until the dyno is restarted (and then it STILL won't work), not until you `pg:psql`.

As far as I know, `pg:psql` only establishes a connection to the remote database, and should not have any consequence on the state of the database server (though it seems it does).

Comment: Alternatively, use the `pg-extras` plugin for Heroku: `heroku plugins:install git://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras.git` and then use `heroku pg:push localdbname DATABASE` to push your local database to the Heroku pg db. More info [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras)